# How many solutions does the equation a+b+c+d+e+f = 2006 have where a, b, c, d, e , and f are all positive integers?

Tags: combinatorics

I know that this is a combinatorical problem. I even have the solution which is given as follows:

> Given that the variables are all positive integers, we can subtract 1 from each of 
>   them and subtract 6 from the other side to obtain a new equation where we are 
>   expressing 2000 as an ordered sum of 6 non-negative integers.  There are 
>   (2000+5 5) = (2005 5)
>    ways to do this.

I can't understand why we have to subtract 1 ? 
I can imagine the whole equation as a line of points which are separated by bars and the points to each bar are actually the number represented by the corresponding variable. So I would have  n-1 bars (if n is the number of variables). But here I can't get why we need to subtract 1 from all of the variables... Thank you in advance !

Comment: The starts 'n' bars method is suitable under the restriction of **non-negative** integers. The problem at hand is restricted to **positive** integers, so you need to reduce it to an equivalent problem with an appropriate restriction.

Comment: @barakmanos: Note that Wikipedia's [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) article gives direct theorems both for the "positive" and the "non-negative" cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write
$$ \underbrace{1+1+1+\cdots+1+1+1}_{2006} $$
Your task is to color $5$ of the $2005$ plus signs red and collapse the rest of them. (Since all of your variables are positive, the same plus sign can't be used twice).

This can be done in $\binom{2005}{5}$ ways.

Comment: is not the answer $\binom {n+r-1}{r} = \binom{2011}{6}$ ?

Comment: @vidyarthi: No -- why would it be? If the six variables were allowed to be zero, the answer would be $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}=\binom{2011}{5}$, but it is explicitly specified here that they _can't_ be zero. Why would that lead to the even higher number $\binom{2011}{6}$?

Comment: thanks, the "positive" and "nonnegative " make a huge impact!